# How to extract the information from MutableLiveData<Resource<Object>> to a simpler object in viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, mutablelivedata

I am trying to get an object from a `MutableLiveData<Resource<ObjectIWant>>` to a `var hereIwantTheObject : ObjectIWant` in my HomeFragment, apparently use the Resource class is the recommended way if you use coroutines and LiveData. The thing is that I want this object on my variable and disatached from MutableLiveData, when I try it says the variable hasn't been initialized. Here my classes and what I have tried

ViewModel class:

```
class HomeFragmentViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val mutableVar: MutableLiveData<Resource<ObjectIwant>> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        getObjectIwantData()
    }

    fun getObjectIwantData() = viewModelScope.launch {
        mutableVar.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        val response = AppRepository().getObjectIwantDataInRepository()
        mutableVar.postValue(handleResponse(response))
    }

    private fun handleResponse(response: Response<ObjectIwant>): Resource<ObjectIwant> {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body()?.let { resultResponse ->
                return Resource.Success(resultResponse)
            }
        }
        return Resource.Error(response.message())
    }
```

HomeFragment class and where I am trying to get the info:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var viewModel: HomeFragmentViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeFragmentViewModel::class.java)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        var hereIwantTheObject: ObjectIwant? = null

        viewModel.brastlewarkTownData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
            response.data?.let { brastlewarkTown ->
                hereIwantTheObject = brastlewarkTown
            }
        })
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: ${hereIwantTheObject!!.name")
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Here the Resource class:

```
sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null
) {
    class Success<T>(data: T) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String, data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data, message)
    class Loading<T> : Resource<T>()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `onCreateView()` is executed, several things happen:

- a local `var hereIwantTheObject` is declared and initialised with `null`
- an observer for the `LiveData<Resource<ObjectIwant>>` object is registered
- the value of the local variable is still `null` but you promise it is not `null` when writing to Logcat
- so at this point your app will crash...

But why is *hereIwantTheObject* still `null`? That's because the observation results for any `LiveData` objects can only come in on the UI thread after execution of the current function `onCreateView()` has finished.

At this point however the local variable will have been discarded, so if you want to be able to assign a value to it later on you need to make it a property:

```
private var hereIwantTheObject: String? = null
```

Now if you delete the line with the local declaration for *hereIwantTheObject* and move the `Log.i(...)` statement to the block which is executed if there are changes to the `LiveData` object, everything will work as desired

```
response.data?.let { brastlewarkTown ->
        hereIwantTheObject = brastlewarkTown
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: ${hereIwantTheObject!!.name}")
    }
```